# How to programmatically clear cached js from a react-node build?

Tags: reactjs, browser-cache

I have an ecommerce that is having a lot of trouble to work nicely because of cache. We started the deployment with register option on service worker and now, even after a week and having set unregister to it, there are still many costumers complaining about not having received updates.

I tried everything, even dropping my old production instance and creating a new one, to see if the browser would understand as a different app, but it did not work out. I also tried putting meta in the index.html, but no success, because index.html is also cached.

Comment: This is a question, that none of the similar questions in SO and the issues in the GitHub repo of CRA does not have a clear answer. even the contributors of the CRA replying in a way that seems this is an issue from another planet :). but among them the best solution I found was to add a script to `index.html` and unregister service worker from navigator `navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => {registration.unregister();});`

Comment: Problem is even index is cached, I put the meta inside it and I had the possibility to access one of the browsers that are a week old cached, and I can't see the meta I've put in. I guess the index is the main problem because it's also the one that calls the scripts, and since scripts are hashed by version, it's calling the old ones that are stored in browser.